# Modern security implementation: operation token sent to the bank by secure server

Tags: banks, token

This post is related to [this post on Android users stack exchange relating to conceiving of a variety of household situations and files](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/254269/258994) and a post related to what immutable storage is which was deleted from this site and deleted (immutable storage is for backup files that cannot be deleted on the server), as well as intellectual property endurance management and preservation.

Suppose the experience of losing a file is an experience of losing a set of plans. You could pay for the experience, but what does it give you. Perhaps, the idea to post on this forum.

I envision a system of file protection that works as follows. But I wish to extend the idea beyond file protection, to a generic mechanism.

There is a server which is a secure server and issues tokens.

In the case of file protection it may be a server that backs up your files as you have been storing them on Google Drive, and you decide what goes on the secure server.

It is not uncommon to have a file that is causing your discomfort or dismay. In that case, you would not be saving it to the secure server (and, someone with, access, to your account, may delete it).

Each token has a specific token operation associated with it.

The operation token Is sent to the bank and the operation can only be authorized by going to the bank, selecting the operation throgh a special screen availavle at and interac likes counter with finger print access and camera surveillance overview. You then have the added security. You can move your backup for example to and from the server where the backup Is stored. Nobody, not even in your home Who has access to your account, can delete the backup, because It would require gaining access to the special token (and only of the server provides that service), the token is only sent to the bank, where it can only be authorized to the person, using theor finger print (and additional special bank card may be necessary, but the finger print (or better body attached or via body identifiable check, such as retina scan or office clerk identification) is essential crucial and require for extra security).

The server issuing the token, can be just another Google Drive server (minicking a separate user account). It would have to have token issuing software.

The two operations I am interested in, which would require a token, are, move backup from Google drive to secure server, and move backup from secure server by making a download link availavle (the secure server can provide the link by issuing a special barcode on the bank screen, that the phone may scan. Then the user has access to the download link.

The reason for writing this, is, that this is and information security site, and I am trying, to make this, (idea usability complete).

I feel that there is still the issue of coersion (I force you to go to the bank and approve a token), but that is not the same as intentionality with regret or thoughtlessness.

You could intentionally delete something and regret it, or delete it due to carelessness. These, are both things, that can happen (and in that case your data is safe in the secure server).

Finally, for neatness (and storage requirements), you could have an upload token that allowed for the successive retrieval of a download token, and another for immutable storage that didn't.

For example, some of the files may even have copyright or patent issues to resolve, but your weren't yet ready, with publication, but the code was important.

It may also be that the content suitability needs further pondering, but you have worked on it, and, your work may entail several versions of pondering.

I feel that in a world of proper files and proper content this idea would be welcome (but I also feel it could have potentially many other uses, such as authorizing the move of hand made crafts from one location to another, or what may be).

Thank you for your consideration.

The question is, why hasn't anyone implemented this solution?

Wouldn't it be nice if it were implemented?

I authorize its use, and hereby put my idea in the public domain, for secure server agencies, agencies, of various kinds, and banks, to implement.

Have a nice day.